# SSRS: Create chart

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I want to create a chart in SSRS where the user can input a time range and maybe selects the wanted *TrackingIDs* for display.

I have a table which has three main columns:

- **ID,**
- **TrackingID and**
- **TrackingTime**

For each *ID* are *TrackingIDs* saved with their corresponding *TrackingTime*. That means that there are multiple rows with the same ID but different TrackingIDs.

```
|   ID   |   TrackingID   |      TrackingTime     |....
|--------|----------------|-----------------------|
|   001  |       10       |2017-03-08 10:12:20.240|
|   003  |       50       |2017-03-08 12:30:23.240|
|   001  |       10       |2017-03-03 09:10:23.240|
|   002  |       10       |2017-03-06 10:12:23.240|
|   001  |       15       |2017-03-05 10:12:23.240|
|   001  |       20       |2017-03-08 17:12:23.240|
|   002  |       15       |2017-03-04 00:12:23.240|
|   003  |       10       |2017-03-06 01:18:23.240|
....
```

The user than receives a chart where the sum of each TrackingID is displayed over time. Out of this chart the user can read the change of TrackingIDs over time.

Important is that only the last given TrackingID for an ID is added to the sum of one kind of TrackingID.

Comment: It is a common task in SSRS and there are plenty resources [[1](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/multiple-parameters-in-ssrs/)] [[2](http://knowlton-group.com/ssrs-reports-with-date-parameters/)] on internet, try something by yourself, if you get stuck in the process edit  your question to include your issue and the necessary information to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two text box parameters to your report that allow user input. I will assume in this case that we are just going to filter between date ranges and not time.

Then go to your table properties and the Filters tab. Add a new Filter.

**Expression:** Press the fx button to add an expression. 
Try this:

> *CDate(Fields!TrackingTime.Value)*

This should convert your DataSet date/time into a VBnet CDate

**Operator:** > or < depending on which parameter we are comparing to (add one for each)

**Value:** Press the fx button to add an expression.
Try this:

> *CDate(Parameters!(YOUR PARAMETER NAME).Value)*

This will convert the user input to a VBnet CDate

Your filter should then be able to successfully compare two CDates and determine if they are greater than or less than. Add one for start and end date and you will get your filtered range.

If CDate doesn't work give this function a try: 
FormatDateTime(Fields!TrackingTime.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)

EDIT: If you are doing this for a chart you can add this as a filter in your data element.